# set SelectedIndex of Combobox in WPF to 0

Tags: c#, wpf

I am binding a Collection at run time to a Combobox and I would like to set the Index after to 0. I could not find a straight answer to what I want.

```
_stationNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(_floorUnits.Unit.Select(f => f.Name));
_stationNames.Insert(0, "All");
stationsComboBox.ItemsSource = _stationNames;
stationsComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;//Doesn;t work
```

Xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="stationsComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"
                  SelectionChanged="StationComboBoxSelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3"
                   SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Comment: You could try setting the SelectedItem instead. Just looking at what you've shown us, I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but create a new string variable "All", insert it into your collection, and assign the combobox selected item to that variable.

Comment: I agree. Create a separate property that represents a single item in your collection and bind it to the SelectedItem property of your ComboBox. Then set that to the first item in the collection.

Comment: Shouldn't need `Text="{Binding Name}"` in your XAML.  This is redundant to your setting of the `ItemsSource`, where there should only be a single column (field) in the results set.  I found it can also cause problems like these where `.SelectedIndex` doesn't get set properly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use it like you would with WinForms. WPF is a slightly different beast and a lot more powerful regarding bindings.

I recommend reading a bit on MVVM to get the most benefit from WPF. By binding the XAML to a view model class (rather than trying to wire things up in Code-behind) you will find you can accomplish what you want with a lot more flexibility without oodles of code.

For instance: Given the following VM:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> StationNames
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Something()
    {
        StationNames = new ObservableCollection<string>( new [] {_floorUnits.Unit.Select(f=>f.Name)});
        StationNames.Insert(0, "All");
    }

    private string _selectedStationName = null;
    public string SelectedStationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedStationName;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedStationName = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedStationName");
        }
    }

    private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can set your view's (XAML form) DataContext to an instance of the ViewModel and update your combo box definition to:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="stationsComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StationNames}" SelectedItem={Binding Path=SelectedStationName} VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3"
                   SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

From here whenever the combo box selection changes, the VM's SelectedStationName updates to reflect the current selection, and from anywhere in the VM code, setting the VM's SelectedStationName will update the combo's selection. (I.e. implementing a Reset button, etc.)

Normally though, with something like what you've suggested, I would be looking at binding directly to  the Units collection. (or VM's derived from units if they themselves can be viewed/edited.) In any case it should give you a bit of a starting point to start researching into WPF bindings.

Comment: *"lot more powerful regarding bindings."* - Meaning; you're going to have to write a lot more code to accomplish the same thing you could in one line using WinForms :D

Comment: Thanks, is there no other way where I can just do it in Codebehind. The files that I have already have everything in code-behind so it would be difficult to change to MVVM at this point.